# can't put a title to the page

Tags: html, image

I can't put a title to the page I tried to use the title tag again with no success.

[image]

the relevant code view:

```
    <h2 align="left"  class="w3-center">לוח מודעות</h2>

    <tr align="left">
        <div align="left" class="w3-content" style="max-width:400px">

            <img align="left" class="mySlides" src="http://www.sapir.ac.il/files/7a790acebf3213f6928cb60fd488471a//styles/epsa_crop_hp_top_banner/public/030717_OPHW8.jpg?itok=dAGknih9" style="width:100%" height="450">
            <img align="left" class="mySlides" src="http://cnd.ash-college.ac.il/.upload/Images/banner_500x251.jpg" style="width:100%" height="450">
            <img align="left" class="mySlides" src="http://www.achva.ac.il/sites/default/files/imagecache/carousel_img/carousel/images/s-yom_new.jpg" style="width:100%" height="450">

        </div>
    </tr>
    <br />
    <br />
    <button id="button1" style="background:#f90;
 color:#fff;font-family:Calibri;
 padding:6px 30px;border:none;
 border-bottom:3px solid #925b08;
 border-radius:10px;
 font-size:200%;"
            type="button"
            onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ShowSearch1","Institution")'">
        חפש מוסד לימודים
    </button>
    &nbsp;
    <button id="button1" dir="rtl" style="background:#f90;
 color:#fff;font-family:Calibri;
 padding:6px 30px;border:none;
 border-bottom:3px solid #925b08;
 border-radius:10px;
 font-size:200%;"
            type="button"
            onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ShowSearch", "Degree")'">
        חפש תואר
```

Comment: Are you trying to add a title to the html page? what is that image has to do with your question?

Comment: what is a table row (`<tr>`) tag doing in your code since you are not adding any column and no tables are defined?